# How can I schedule Windows 10 to automatically impose the 'grayscale' colour filter once a day?

Tags: windows, filter, colors, settings, schedule

I find that I'm more effective and less easily distracted when I have the 'grayscale' colour filter enabled on Windows 10.  This is usually changed in 'Settings->Ease of Access->Colour Filters', and there is a keyboard shortcut of 'Ctrl+Windows+C' which toggles the setting.  Unfortunately I'm often in a habit of disabling it temporarily and forgetting to re-enable it.

So is it at all possible to schedule windows to set the filter to 'grayscale' automatically once a day or a couple of times a day, so that if I do disable it temporarily and then forget to re-enable, it'll do this automatically for me?

Thankyou.

I'm aware of Task Scheduler, and I'm guessing some sort of .bat script would work, but I have no idea what to write in the .bat file.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three potential solutions:

1. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1446401/automatically-turn-on-grayscale-mode-in-windows-10) is a solution from a StackExchange partner site, via an AutoHotkey script plus Task Scheduler.
2. An alternative if you wanted to toggle grayscale once per day would be the Windows app [Auto Dark Mode](https://github.com/AutoDarkMode/Windows-Auto-Night-Mode), available on MS Store [here](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/auto-dark-mode/XP8JK4HZBVF435). It's mainly for toggling between Light and Dark mode on scheduled times, but in Settings there's an option to "Use color filter (sends Win + Ctrl + C)". If you used that setting plus set the options in the Apps tab to "Always light", I expect this would be equivalent to having the app toggle grayscale once per day.
3. This [article on HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/809031/how-to-schedule-dark-mode-on-windows-11/) describes how to toggle Windows dark mode via Task Scheduler and the Windows registry, and I expect this method could be adapted to toggling grayscale, too. Based on a comment on the first solution plus some brief trial & error, the registry key in question seems to be the `DWORD` item `Active` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ColorFiltering\`. But I don't recommend tampering with the Windows Registry if other options are available, and won't vouch for this suggested solution.